# Yes or No option

Tags: python, iteration

Hi I have the following

This will iterate 10 times to begin with..I would like a prompt to user Y for Yes .N for No after it has reached 10 and then return a prompt to the user to enter a new number in a while loop,similar to what I have below..(if not a number ,repeat until a number is entered). but with the intention to just enter a new number of iterations..

At this point if N is entered exit the program...Y will display and infinite loop hence the return -1 ...and so will "" ..(empty)

Thanks for any help.

```
def my_func(c=1, n=-1):
    while True:
        if n>-1 and c > n:
            # if counter > number of iterations required
            break
        a = int(c * (c + 1)/2)
        yield a
        c += 1

def get_valid_user_input():
    user_input = input("Enter a number, or leave blank for infinite loop: ")
    if user_input == "":
        return -1
    try:
        return int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error! Please enter a number or leave blank.")
        return get_valid_user_input()

first_try = my_func(n=10)

while True:

    try:

        print(next(first_try))

    except StopIteration:

        print("End of Iteration")

        break
while True:

    my_object = my_func(n=get_valid_user_input())

    while True:

          try:

            print(next(my_object))

          except StopIteration:

            print("End of Iteration")

            break
```

Comment: Don't use recursion in `get_valid_user_input`. You might want to read: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Is there a way someone can give an example in my code..I read that topic but I'm still unclear